# Does rebuild index do the equivalent of dropping and recreating the indexes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, indexing

I spent a couple of hours yesterday and today trying to troubleshoot why a particular database query was taking long (3+ minutes) to execute on a database that I restored on my local instance yet it was taking only a fraction of a second on the production server. (Its not just a question of the production server having a higher spec since the same query has been executing fine on my local instance previously).

I am going to trying explain the problem the best way I can - means the post might be a bit long. The query is pretty straight-forward:

```
SELECT [t0].[BillId], [t0].[CustomerId], [t0].[BillDate], [t0].[DueDate], 
[t0].[Period], [t0].[Total], [t0].[Balance], [t0].[DateCreated], [t0].[DateModified] --, other fields
FROM [dbo].[Bills] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Period] = 201307) AND (([t0].[DateModified] >= '2013-07-04 17:00:00.000') 
OR (([t0].[DateModified] < '2013-07-04 17:00:00.000') AND (EXISTS(
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[BillDetails] AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[BillID] = [t0].[BillID] AND [t1].[DateModified] >= '2013-07-04 17:00:00.000'
))))
```

The above query returns bills that are associated with a certain period and that have been modified since a particular point in time. A bill is considered modified if the value in its *DateModified* field is later than the specified date or if the value on *DateModified* field in the related child rows (`BillDetails`) is later than the specified date. I'll use the word "delta" in reference to the results returned by the above query.

Its kind of strange, but on my local instance, execution of this query seems to kind of block specifically when there is no delta i.e. when there have been no changes to `Bills` and `BillDetails` since the last specified date. When there is delta to return, the query takes a fraction of a second. On the live/production database, the query responds very fast for both scenario.

I have come across this problem once before but I didn't document how I fixed it - most probably because I couldn't figure out what fixed it out of the many things I tried. During that time, the "blocking" was happening on the production database while my local instance was just fine. I suspected it had something to do with the indexes.

When it now recurred on my local instance the indexes were the prime suspects. I ran I utility script I have for reorganizing indexes with an average fragmentation of between 5 and 30 percent and rebuilding indexes with an average fragmentation of over 30 percent. That didn't appear to solve the problem. I have tried a lot of things since, but the one that fixed it is dropping and recreating the non-clustered indexes on the `Bills` table.

I have three non-clustered indexes on the `Bills` table defined as follows (more or less):

```
NCI_IDX1 ([CustomerId] ASC)
NCI_IDX2 ([CustomerId] ASC, [Period] ASC, [BillId] ASC)
NCI_IDX3_Inc_Various ([Period] ASC, [DateModified] ASC, [BillId] ASC, [CustomerId] ASC) INCLUDE ([BillDate], [Total], [Balance] /* more fields */)
```

From my experience while trying to resolve the issue, I have a few questions gnawing at my mind.

**Q**: What does rebuild index do? Does it do the equivalent of manually dropping and recreating the indexes

**Q**: Dropping an index results into the statistic(s) associated with the index getting dropped. Does rebuilding of indexes "refresh" or "reset" the related statistics?

**Q**: Given the reliance of query optimizer on statistics when choosing the execution plan, could the statistics have been responsible for the perceived blocking of the query execution?

**Q**: According to MSDN, statistics on indexes cannot be dropped using `DROP STATISTICS`. Does that mean that one has to drop and recreate the indexes in order to reset the statistics?

*NOTE*: LINQ and C# are tagged since the origin of the above query is a C# application using LINQtoSQL in the data layer.

Answer (score 1):

i have found this sentence:

> However, an index **reorganize does not update statistics** at all
>   because  the entire    table is not analyzed in one go (only pages
>   with fragmentation are reorganized).

at this article: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-accidental-dba-day-15-of-30-statistics-maintenance/

maybe your script for rebuiding/reorganizing indexes just **reorganized** the index, but did not **rebuild** it (due to low fragmentation) and so the statistics on this index became "old".

there is a good suggestion in the article:

> So, if you find that your index maintenance scripts are regularly
>   reorganizing indexes then you’ll want to make sure that you also add
>   in statistics maintenance.